# TypeError: data type 'category' not understood pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`, with `dtypes: category(16), float32(65), int32(41)`.  I want to perform some analysis on the categorical column. but when I iterate through the columns I get the above error. I can't seem to figure out what might be the issue.

```
for col in app_train:
    if app_train[col].dtype == 'category':
        pass
```

Traceback

```
TypeError  (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-603a6aa31592> in <module>
      5 # Iterate through the columns
      6 for col in app_train:
----> 7     if app_train[col].dtype == 'category':
                pass


TypeError: data type 'category' not understood
```

Comment: As an aside, equals comparison to `'catgegory'` works as expected in `pandas 1.3.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.api.types` module to check any data types, it's the most recommended way to go about it. It contains a function [`pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_categorical.html) that allows you to check if the datatype is categircal. If you are using slightly older version of pandas, you can use `pd.api.types.is_categorical` if `is_categorical_dtype` is missing on your pandas version.

```py
for col in app_train:
    if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(app_train[col]):
        pass
```

If you want to use `dtype` attribute, then use `name` value for the `dtype`:

```py
for col in app_train:
    if app_train[col].dtype.name == 'category':
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this slight adjust could help.
User `app_train.columns` to use It's names to check the dtype.

```
for col in app_train.columns:
    if app_train[col].dtype == 'category':
        pass
```

Comment: When iterating over a DataFrame it will already provide the columns. There is no difference between this code and OPs in terms of the values produced by the `for`.

Comment: @codan The above soln throw the same error as before.